# Display Timecode for video track using Swift AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, timecodes

I am working on a little app to navigate and play videos which includes **framerate** and initial **timecode** information (eg: `"TimeCode" : "09:25:15:08"`). I am using the `AVKit Player View Controller` to display my video, and I would like to add a UILabel displaying the current timecode.

I'm all set about the way to add up custom UI elements, but I'm lost about how to calculate the `timecode` and make it update itself every frame the video plays.

I have read about the [AVFoundation - Timecode Support with AVAssetWriter and AVAssetReader](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2310/_index.html), but I'm not sure if I have understood it.

Any explanations, guidance, or content to look at would be really appreciated.

UPDATE:

After thinking for a while, I though that I could use the frame count to build up my own timecode references.

note **item is the AVPlayer**

using `var totalTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(item.currentItem.asset.duration)`I can get the total length in seconds of the video track, and `currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(item.currentItem.currentTime())`to get its current time position.

Then I can do `var fps = item.currentItem.asset.tracks[0].nominalFrameRate`to get the framerate and use this variable to divide `totalTime` and `currentTime`to get the total frame count as well as the current frame.

With this im considering the idea of building up a pre normalized array of time in second for each frame from the total frame count. this way I could know what exact frame is related to a time stamp.

I never had to work with timecode or dates so if someone has an idea about the way to do this I would appreciate the help.

basically, a timecode looks like this: `HH:MM:SS:FF` (FF being the current frame).
If the fps = 24, then every 24 frames a second is added to the SS and so on.

TEST CASE:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player = AVPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var url=NSURL(string: "http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1211/sample_iTunes.mov")
        player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        playerController.player = player
        self.addChildViewController(playerController)
        self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
        playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

        //Debug btn
        var btn = UIButton()
        btn.frame = CGRect(x:10, y:50, width:100, height:30)
        btn.setTitle("FPS", forState: .Normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        playerController.view.addSubview(btn)

        player.play()
//        getFps(player)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func getFps(item:AVPlayer) {
        var fps = item.currentItem.asset.tracks[0].nominalFrameRate
        println("FPS: \(fps)")

        var timeRange_src = CMTimeGetSeconds(item.currentItem.asset.duration)
        var timeRange = Float(timeRange_src)
        println("time Range: \(timeRange)")
        var frameCount = timeRange * fps
        println("total frames: \(frameCount)")

        var timeIs = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(item.currentItem.currentTime()))
        var frameIs = timeIs * fps
        println("current time: \(timeIs)")
        println("current frame: \(frameIs)")

    }

    func buttonTapAction(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        getFps(player)
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok so here is how I solved my problem and built the timecode based on the variables I had:

```
func pad(fps:Float, currentFrame:Float) -> (String){
        var fps = fps
        var frame = currentFrame + f
        var ff = frame % fps
        var seconds = s + ((currentFrame) / fps)
        var ss = seconds % 60
        var minutes = m + ((seconds - ss) / 60)
        var mm = minutes % 60
        var hh = h + ((minutes - mm) / 60)
        return "\(showTwoDigits(hh)):\(showTwoDigits(mm)):\(showTwoDigits(ss)):\(showTwoDigits(ff))"
    }

    func showTwoDigits(number:Float) -> (String){
        var string = ("00" + String(format:"%.f", number))
        var range = Range(start: (advance(string.endIndex, -2)), end: string.endIndex)
        var cutStr = string.substringWithRange(range)
        return cutStr
    }
```

Comment: This will work fine for framerates like 24 (movie) or 25 (PAL) but not correctly for the 29.97 you get by default (NTSC). See "Drop Frame Timecode"

Comment: Code does not compile because you are missing many variables!

Comment: This was written in Swift 1, it would need to be updated

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I recently did it with Swift 3:

```
func formatTimecode(frame: Int, fps: Double) -> String {
    let FF = Int(Double(frame).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: fps))
    let seconds = Int(Double(frame - FF) / fps)
    let SS = seconds % 60
    let MM = (seconds % 3600) / 60
    let HH = seconds / 3600

    let timecode = [String(format: "%02d", HH), String(format: "%02d", MM), String(format: "%02d", SS), String(format: "%02d", FF)];

    return timecode.joined(separator: ":")
}
```